# Verilog 8bits to X and X to 8 again

Tags: verilog, fpga, mojo

I've recently bought Mojo v3 which already has the UART module to communicate with the AVR and from the AVR to the computer.
My problem is: how do I connect this with other modules?
Let's say that I have a MD5 core that accepts X bytes, what's the best approach to read from the serial X chars until Enter is pressed and then send it back to the MD5 core?
Ok, I'm a newbie, let alone MD5, let's say that I just want to make a simple echo.
Where should I start? using FIFO? shift registers? simple arrays? BRAM?
This is the AVR interface (UART):

```
module avr_interface(
    input clk,
    input rst,
    input cclk,

    output spi_miso,
    input spi_mosi,
    input spi_sck,
    input spi_ss,
    output [3:0] spi_channel,

    output tx,
    input rx,

    input [3:0] channel,
    output new_sample,
    output [9:0] sample,
    output [3:0] sample_channel,

    input [7:0] tx_data,
    input new_tx_data,
    output tx_busy,
    input tx_block,

    output [7:0] rx_data,
    output new_rx_data
);
```

I'm using this tutorial as a base to learn more: 
http://embeddedmicro.com/tutorials/mojo/hello-world/

I've already made a simple echo byte by byte, but this is not the point. I just want the string echoed back when Enter is pressed.
Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
Mojo developer made an awesome example here:
http://embeddedmicro.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=697&start=10

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To echo back an arbitrary length block, you're going to need a FIFO and some sort of state machine to control it.  The FIFO input will be connected to the bus coming from the UART RX module.  The FIFO output will be connected to the bus going to the UART TX module.  There also needs to be a way to 'block' the ouptput of the FIFO so that it will not send a byte.  Easist way to do that is just to AND a control signal with the 'ready' signal going to the FIFO and the 'valid' signal going from the FIFO to the UART TX module.

Then all the state machine has to do is look at the data on both ends of the FIFO.  Whenever an enter keypress is received, increment a counter.  Whenever an enter keypress comes out of the FIFO, decrement the counter.  When the counter is greater than zero, unblock the FIFO output.  Otherwise, block it so no data comes out.

If you want to send specific data to a specific module, then what you should do is define a binary packet format of some sort.  Basically, you'll need some sort of start identifier for framing and probably some sort of type identifier, followed by the data.  Then on the FPGA you can wait for the start delimiter, check the type, then load the bytes into registers in order as they come in.  Once you've received the entire packet, then you can send whatever module you're communicating with a signal that all the data is ready.